# How can i combine pyspark, graphene and flask together?

Tags: python, flask, pyspark, graphql, graphene-python

In my code i'm using `pyspark` for data manipulation, python `graphene` for building a `graphql` server around my data, and `flask` to serve the graphql api. 
But i am facing some problems which i don't know the reason why it occurs.

Basically the code doesn't compute the correct results, and i'm hypothesing on some maybe concurrency issue overall.

Here's a simplification of my code:

```
import graphene
from flask import Flask
from flask_graphql import GraphQLView

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

app = Flask(__name__)

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Sencivil") \
    .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv")\
    .option("sep", ";")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .load("./people.csv")\
    .cache()


class Birthdate(graphene.ObjectType):
    boys = graphene.Int()
    girls = graphene.Int()

    def __init__(self, bd):
        self.bd = bd

    def resolve_boys(self, info):
        boys = df.where(df.gender == 1).groupby("birthdate").count()
        return boys.count()

    def resolve_girls(self, info):
        girls = df.where(df.gender == 2).groupby("birthdate").count()
        return girls.count()


class Person(graphene.ObjectType):
    born = graphene.List(Birthdate)

    def resolve_born(self, info):
        bds = [Birthdate(row.asDict()["birthdate"])
               for row in df.select("birthdate").collect()]
        return bds


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    people = graphene.Field(Person)

    def resolve_people(self, info):
        return Person()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

app.add_url_rule(
    "/graphql", view_func=GraphQLView.as_view('graphql', schema=schema, graphiql=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**people.csv**

```
birthdate;gender
13-01-1987;1
02-09-1986;2
13-01-1987;1
02-09-1986;2
12-04-1998;1
```

The problem resides at the `resolve_boys` and `resolve_girls` methods of the `Birthdate` class where i'm expecting to get 2 for the boys and 1 for the girls as we can see directly from the pyspark shell:

```
>>> boys = df.where(df.gender == 1).groupby("birthdate").count()
>>> boys.show()
+----------+-----+                                                              
| birthdate|count|
+----------+-----+
|13-01-1987|    2|
|12-04-1998|    1|
+----------+-----+

>>> girls = df.where(df.gender == 2).groupby("birthdate").count()
>>> girls.show()
+----------+-----+                                                              
| birthdate|count|
+----------+-----+
|02-09-1986|    2|
+----------+-----+
```

But instead i'm just getting 0's from the api:

[image: GraphiQL]

So how to solve this issue?

If i changed the code where it is reading the csv file to instead creating a dataframe locally like this

```
# df = spark.read.format("csv")\
#     .option("sep", ";")\
#     .option("header", "true")\
#     .load("./people.csv")\
#     .cache()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [{'birthdate': "13-01-1987", "gender": 1},
     {'birthdate': "02-09-1986", "gender": 2}, 
     {'birthdate': "13-01-1987", "gender": 1},
     {'birthdate': "02-09-1986", "gender": 2}, 
     {'birthdate': "12-04-1998", "gender": 1}]
)
```

i get the correct answer:

[image]

So the problem occurs when reading the csv file. But why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your issue? It seems like the dataframe is not properly loaded as you pointed out but I believe it is caused by this line `.load("./people.csv")\` which is not pointing to your csv file.

Just in case, can you wrap your code in a try-except block to print out either the dataframe or the error response?

Cheers!